# Rotate 1 screen in React native (both ios and android)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm coding an application React-Native in which i need one screen to be locked on landscape (without any action from the user), how can i do this ?
I tried the "transform" props but couldn't manage to make it works

Answer (score 0):

In Android :
Navigate to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. the path is `android/app/src/main` and set `android:screenOrientation` to the `landscape`.

In iOS:
Open iOS folder of your project with Xcode. In `general` tab, find device orientation and set it to landscape left or right.

The abovementioned is ok to change the orientation of all the screens. if you need to change one particular page only, you can use this [library](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation).

Comment: doesn't it change the orientation of all my screen (and i don't want that) ?

Comment: if you need for 1 page only, you can try this library: https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation